# Full names of C. K. Chow and C. N. Liu

Tags: reference-request

Where can I find the full names of C. K. Chow and C. N. Liu, of the Chow-Liu tree fame?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow%E2%80%93Liu_tree

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1054142

Comment: I'm also trying to locate Kozachenko's full first name: http://www.mathnet.ru/eng/person42864

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I could find, the names are

- Chao-Kong Chow
- Chao-Ning Liu

I found the second from [this IEEE note](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5391046), which links Chao-Ning Liu to IBM Thomas .J. Watson (which he joined in 1957). Then, a search for patents gave the name of C.K. Chow.

C.K. Chow's name is also stated in [this paper by O'Donnell and Servedio](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eodonnell/papers/chow-params.pdf) on The Chow Parameters Problem (see abstract).

Comment: Some details from O'Donnell: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/knuth.html

Comment: More pictures of Chow here: https://online.fliphtml5.com/qwnc/bwtp/. Unfortunately, he has passed away in 2016.

Answer (score 5):

And since a comment also asked for the full name of L. F. Kozachenko (of the Kozachenko-Leonenko entropy estimate fame), here it is: Lyudmyla Fedoryvna Kozachenko.

Comment: How did you find that out?

Comment: I emailed Prof. Leonenko.

Comment: How did you find information about Leonenko?

Comment: On his website... https://www.cardiff.ac.uk/people/view/98655-leonenko-nikolai

Comment: I actually found it on his mathscinet profile, https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/author.html?mrauthid=112700